# Adding to a private variable not working

Tags: c++, variables, private

I'm currently learning c++ and trying to make a vending machine! I know my code is really bad and I am sorry about that.
I am trying to implement a bank and have the user take a loan from it, the only problem is that the bank is unable to add money to the user. Here's my code.

```
void Bank::askLoan() {
//ColaMachine object
ColaMachine cola;

bool loanGranted = false;

cout << string(100, '\n');
cout << "You do not have enough money!\n\n";
cout << "Would you like to take a loan?\n\n(1)-Yes\n(2)-No\n\n\n";
int choice;
cin >> choice;

switch (choice) {
case 1:
    //Print the bank menu!

    printBank();
    while (loanGranted != true) {
        cout << "Enter the amount to lend: $";
        cin >> _loanValue;
        //Test if _loanValue is less than or = to bankmoney, so they would scam the bank.
        if (_loanValue <= _bankMoney) {
            //Supposed to add money to the user.
            cola.addMoney(_loanValue);
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "You entered too much! Try again..." << endl;
        }
    }
    break;
case 2:
    //User does not want to take a loan! Quit the game!
    //Not implemented, yet.
    break;
default:
    cout << "Bad input! Please retry..." << endl;
}
```

}

If the amount entered was within the correct range it calls the addMoney() Func from ColaMachine class.

```
void ColaMachine::addMoney(int money) {

//This part doesnt seem to modify the actual value
//Whenever It goes back to the main game loop it doesnt change.
_money += money;
```

}

From what I understand += is the same as _money = _money + money;

What am I doing wrong here?
Full source on GitHub-
https://github.com/Rohukas/-LearningCPP

Comment: _doesnt seem to modify_ What does that mean? How do you know?

Comment: `From what I understand += is the same as _money = _money + money;` correct.  But it sounds like you should learn about using your debugger.

Comment: Read about local variables in your favourite C++ book and think about what `cola` is. (It would do you well to get into the habit of separating user interaction from data processing.)

Comment: BTW: what in the world do bank loans and cola machines have to do with each other?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
void Bank::askLoan() {
//ColaMachine object
ColaMachine cola;
bool loanGranted = false;
...
```

everytime you call `Bank::askLoad` you create a new `ColaMachine`, that's what the code above says. But the problem is that any changes to that `ColaMachine` are thrown away when you exit `Bank::askLoan` and the `ColaMachine` is destroyed. That's why the changes you make to the `ColaMachine` don't stick.

Instead you want to use same `ColaMachine` each time that you call `Bank::askLoad`. I can't say the best way to do that without seeing the rest of your code, but one way would be to pass `ColaMachine` as a reference parameter to `Bank::askLoad`

```
void Bank::askLoan(ColaMachine& cola) {
bool loanGranted = false;
...
```

Another way would be to make `ColaMachine` a class member variable of `Bank`

```
class Bank
{
    ...
    void askLoan();
private:
    ColaMachine cola;
};
```

Which is better? No idea. I think you need to read up on class design, and how the objects in your program should relate to each other. That seems to be the bit you're not getting at the moment.

=========================================================================

Having looked at your full code I can see that you make the same mistake in more than one place. In your `main` function you declare a `Bank` and a `ColaMachine`.

```
//ColaMachine Object
ColaMachine cola;
//Bank Object
Bank bank;
```

Those should be the only two `Bank` and `ColaMachine` objects you create, so this is wrong

```
void ColaMachine::chooseDrink() {
    Bank bo;
    ...
    bo.askLoan();
```

That `Bank bo` is a **completely different** bank from the one you declared in `main`. And like the previous code this `Bank bo` gets created and destroyed each time you call `ColaMachine::chooseDrink`.

I think that what you should be doing is passing the ColaMachine and Bank variables declared in main as reference parameters to the other parts of you code that need to use them. So (for instance)

```
void ColaMachine::chooseDrink(Bank& bank) {
    ...
    bank.askLoan();
```

You have quite a lot of rewriting of this code to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating new cola object inside `askLoan()` method which gets destroyed at the end of the function, so call to `addMoney()` method modifies state of that temporary cola object. One option is to provide cola object by pointer to the `askLoan()` method. 
For example, in `ColaMachine::chooseDrink()` you would call `bo.askLoan(this)`. `this` is pointer to the object from where you call `bo.askLoan()`.
You would need to modify your `askLoan()` signature:
`void askLoan(ColaMachine * cola)` and remove `ColaMachine cola;` from `askLoan()` itself.